# Haskell the function 'main' is not defined?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Here is my basic program, but it states the function 'main' is not defined in module 'Main' how can I fix this?

here is my program

```
main = do
-- variable
a <- getLine
putStrLn a
```

Comment: You are missing indentation.

Comment: could you explain? this is my first time with haskell, as where would i put them?

Comment: You have to indent the two lines `a <- getLine` and `putStrLn a`, both equally far.

Comment: Strange, I ran this without a problem (I thought it would produce an error for the parser).

Comment: Although, without any indentation, you should get a parse error.

Comment: It seems you used tabs, and the display of the code here is misleading. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought I would get a parse error too with no indentation but ghc 6.12, 6.12.3, 7.04 7.4.2, 7.6.2, 7.7 all run the code with zero indentation just fine, at least with runhaskell and the few I check by compiling to an executable worked fine as well.

Comment: @Davorak It's because `NondecreasingIndentation` is on by default (well, that's how it's called since 7.2), a known and intentional deviation from the standard (which I don't like, unlike some other deviations), as I just discovered. `-XHaskell2010` or `-XNoNondecreasingIndentation` [ghc >= 7.2] make it throw a parse error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is missing indentation, Haskell uses indentation to figure out where a block ends.

```
main = do
    a <- getLine
    putStrLn a
```

Above is the proper indented form of your code; you should probably read the article [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) which explains it far better than I.

Comment: I think that is an artifact caused by the OP's use of tabs.

Comment: If it is the case that it is a copy-paste error then I haven't a clue what the problem is with the (seemingly valid) code presented in the question - the only error I can see is the formatting.

Comment: Yes, and if that formatting was real, it should produce a parse error (only GHC doesn't produce one, it accepts the code, gotta check whether that's intentional).

Comment: My copy of GHCI bails with an error message when I run this, and plain GHC bails as well.

Comment: Which version is that? (I need `-XNoNondecreasingIndentation` or `-XHaskell2010` for it to adhere to the standard with respect to the indentation in do-blocks).

Comment: Sorry, got lost browsing. GHC(I) version 7.4.2 from an install of the haskell platform, no special options. I'm on Win32, could this be due to different configurations?

Comment: Hmm, odd. My 7.4.2 takes the indentationless code without a complaint unless I tell it to not use `NondecreasingIndentation`.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means simply that the compiler didn't find a definition of your function `main`.

To run your compiled program, rather than interact with it in ghci (which I'd recommend you do as a beginner), you need `main::IO ()`.

If you don't give your module a name, it automagically does the equivalent of inserting `module Main where` at the top of your file.

I can't think of any way to produce this error other than to

- accidentally comment out main with `--` or `{-` other comment syntax `-}`
- spell the word `main` incorrectly
- accidentally compile an empty file.

---

(
Although your question appears to show incorrect indentation, that's because this site does not treat tabs as 8 characters wide. I suspect you indented the `main` by four spaces to get it to format as code in your question. In any case the compiler didn't give an error message consistent with an indentation error.

I'd like to recommend you use spaces rather than tabs for indentation, as it's unfailingly irritating to have to debug the whitespace of your program.

Most editors can be configured to turn a tab key press into an appropriate number of spaces, giving you the same line-it-up functionality with none of the character count discrepancies.
)